# Create datepicker at an instance of creating a Dynamic Table using a JavaScript function call

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I have created a Dynamic Table by invoking a fucntion using Java Script. My function creates 5 columns of which 3 are text boxes. For the 1st text box I want to create a datepicker instead of the text box. Is it possible. Here is my function code.

```
function insertRow(X)
    {
        eval(X);
```

//nodeArray = HarvestEstimate.Blocks; is the value that I'm getting through a procedure call from my cs file. 
            nodeArray = HarvestEstimate.Blocks;

```
       for (var count = 0; count < nodeArray.length; count++)
       {
            var table=document.getElementById("statstable");
            var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

            var text = nodeArray[count]["Block"];
            var value = nodeArray[count]["BlockId"];

            var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
            var t1=document.createElement("Label");
                t1.for = "lblBlockID"+index;
                t1.innerHTML  = text;;
                cell1.appendChild(t1);

            var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
            var t2=document.createElement("Lable");
                t2.for = "lblBlockName"+index;
                t2.innerHTML  = value; // ;
                cell2.appendChild(t2);
```

// This is WHERE I WANT TO HAVE A DATE PICKER. As of now it is a textbox for "cell3"

```
            var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
            var t3=document.createElement("input");
                t3.id = "txtEstStartDt"+index;
                cell3.appendChild(t3);


            var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
            var t4=document.createElement("input");
                t4.id = "txtEstTotes"+index;
                cell4.appendChild(t4);

            var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
            var t5=document.createElement("input");
                t5.id = "txtEstPicks"+index;
                cell5.appendChild(t5);

                index++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Were you able to find out a solution..

Answer (score 1):

If you browser is compatible with HTML5, u can use

```
 <input type="date" />
```

just write

```
 t3.type="date";
```

before

```
 cell3.appendChild(t3);
```

---

EDIT:

Using HTML5: [jsfiddle.net/k30w0mhd/1](http://jsfiddle.net/k30w0mhd/1)

Using jQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/k30w0mhd/2/

Comment: Thank u for responding to my query. But I'm not getting a datepicker. OnClick it's still a text box. And I'm using Mozilla browser

Comment: This is working in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/k30w0mhd/1/
For Mozilla you may use jquery Datepicker http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Hi can u please help me a bit.In the link that you've provided, the datepicker is initialized in the html body. However in my case I want it to be in the function body. Any help in this regards will be great. I've been on this for the whole day. In the sample snippet, in the html body they have added "<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
"

Answer (score 1):

```
var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
var t3=document.createElement("input");
t3.id = "txtEstStartDt"+index;
t3.className = "datepicker";
cell3.appendChild(t3);
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

You could try the above jquery code..

Remember to reference the jquery library like this..

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this code, but this is not displaying anything. All the other text boxes are also not appearing.

Comment: To use jquery, we need to reference the jquery library.. <head> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> </head> Have you added these lines..

Comment: Yes I did Rajesh. The date picker if added in the main HTML body, it is getting populated. It is not working with the dynamically created datepicker row. The response is also able to capture the id generated for dynamically added row, but it fails to populate the datepicker.

Comment: I have edited the answer now.. You could try that.. I just swapped the last two lines..